# Error is shown. I wanna return the value from If(){}

Tags: java

This is my Binary Search program. I'm searching for `Item=a[4]=5`. How can I return the value from if statement which is present in the while loop without declaring the return statement outside the loop.

```
package Array;

class myArray
{
    int a[]= {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    //this block is only for printing the array
    {
        for(int i=0; i<=9;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(a[i]);
        }
    }
    public int LocationFinder()
    {   
        int Start=a[0],End=a[9],Item=a[4],loc=0;
        while(Start<=End)
        {
            int mid=(Start+End)/2;
            if(Item==mid)
            {
            Item=loc;
            return loc; // <-- I want to return from here
            }
            else if(Item>mid)
            {
                Start=mid+1;
            }
            else
                End=mid-1;


        }

    }
```

I want to return from the above location but an error occurs. How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: What error are you getting? Include logs or stacktraces.

Comment: First of all you are missing `return`'s, this this isn't going to even going to compile.

Comment: What happens if `Start > End`? The `while` loop ends and the method returns ..... *what?!?*

Comment: this is the binary search program how can i return the value from if statement???

Comment: Title says *"Error is shown"*, but you don't actually show us the error you get, which is something like "This method must return a result of type int", because you don't have a `return` statement after the loop, and the loop *can* end, so what is the return value then?

Comment: *"...how can i return the value from if which is present in while **without declaring the return statement** outside the loop"* You can't, the function ***must*** return a value for all possible branches.

Comment: then what should i do? i just want to do binary search. . .i used return in if i suppose it will work. but it shown error. . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method should look like this:

Using Indexing:

```
public int LocationFinder()
    {   
          int Start=0,End=arr.length - 1,Item=a[4];
//Item = key 

while(Start<=End)
        {
            int mid=Start + (End-Start)/2;
            //Checking if item is present at mid     
            if(arr[mid]==Item)
            {
            return mid; //returning the index 
            }
            //if item is greater, than ignore the left side
            else if(arr[mid]<Item)
            {
                Start=mid+1;
            }
            //if item is smaller, than ignore the right side
            else
                End=mid-1;
 }
//returning -1 if the value is not found
return -1;
}
```

Using values:

```
   public int LocationFinder()
            {   
          int Start=arr[0],End=arr[length - 1],Item=a[4];
//Item = key 

        while(Start<=End)
                {
                    int mid=(Start + End)/2;
                    //Checking if item is present at mid     
                    if(arr[mid]==Item)
                    {
                    return mid; //returning the index 
                    }
                    //if item is greater, than ignore the left side
                    else if(arr[mid]<Item)
                    {
                        Start=mid+1;
                    }
                    //if item is smaller, than ignore the right side
                    else
                        End=mid-1;
         }
        //returning -1 if the value is not found
        return -1;
        }
```

for future help see this:

[Binary Search](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search/)

Comment: basically, in first if statement ,write "return mid"

Comment: Thank you it is more help full to me Thank you

Comment: @ShahirZain i always glad to help peoples, Ask more questions when you get in some problem.

Comment: yup i have another question. . .How can i use the interface method without access modifier???

Comment: @ShahirZain see this : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_interfaces.htm and learn from tuotrialpoint the basics of OOP and Java and when you come across the problem in coding then post it on stackoverflow with the code so that you get help.  Happing Coding !